# SQL Server Import BacPac with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to import a data-tier application `.bacpac` file using T-SQL to SQL Server 2019 - but not with the SSMS wizard. This is possible with in T-SQL with `restore database`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Is there something similar for `.bacpac` files?

Comment: Not with T-SQL. You can import a bacpac using the sqlpackage utility or programmatically in C# or PowerShell with DacFx (https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx).

Comment: Awesome, thank you @DanGuzman, that saves me more hours of fruitless searching.